# Site search spam

Tags: search, robots.txt

Our site has been receiving lots of spammy searches, for random keywords, and these results have started to show in Google:

[image: screenshot 1]

I have found that sites are linking to these searches:

[image: screenshot 2]

Our `robots.txt` file currently has:

```
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
```

Should we change this to:

```
Disallow: */catalogsearch/*
```

to prevent these links being crawled?

Is there anything else we should be doing to prevent this spam?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Disallow: /catalogsearch/ should be enough in my opinion

Comment: use .htaccess rules to block/filter  `catalogsearch` , robots.txt file not always works...

Comment: Try this question at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, it will be better received there. It is not a Magento platform specific question in it's current form.